# .htaccess rewrite to php preprocessor causing delay

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

All images, css and js requests to the site need to be forced through pre-processor php scripts.

The following partial rule subset in the parent .htaccess works for css requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
...
# if request is for a css file then send to the css preprocessor - but block direct access
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ %{ENV:ps}%{HTTP_HOST}/inc/css/css.php?f=$1.css [QSA]
...
```

However, the process is slowed by the client's browser being given a 302 and a 301 prior to receiving a 200 from the remapped request.

This is both time consuming over the net (some 50-400ms - even worse for slow client connections) severely holding up the page display or causing reflow in the case of css requests,
and,
is a potential security risk by exposing the workings of the site (existence of pre-processors)

I am no Apache/.htaccess expert - far from it, but feel that there should be some way to force this pre-processing totally on the server and not exposed to the client. I have looked at using other flags [F] and [E] and these seem to fail completely causing a 400 response.
I would also wish to avoid the use of mod_proxy as I am pretty certain the hosting company blocks that, and I have read somewhere that using the proxy [PT] flag has serious problems with timing and sessions.

Is there a flag I am missing? = lack of understanding.

On a side issue, hopefully unrelated, I ran the .htaccess file through this testing [1]: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ only to find that the remap above is being issued as mysite.com/mysite.com/inc/css/css.php?f=any.css instead of just mysite.com/inc/css/css.php?f=any.css

Comment: Why would you pre-process on the fly? Why not just pre-process in advance and have your CSS files ready and waiting?

Comment: css and js and images are supplied pre-prepared based on user/visitors authentication/preferred language/selected style/authority level/location/user-agent/etc...  The .htaccess is inherited and performs several other tasks I only included a snippet above. I have no stomach to re-engineer the whole site, just trying to resolve the inherent slowness and resulting unhappy user interface.